# How to check the function condition inside the list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Hi i was trying to find out if there is a way to do it.

```
number_list = [d(x) for x in range(1, 10001) if d(x) < 10000]
```

I want to use list comprehension something like this.

So basically, I want to have a list items with the function result that is less than 10000.

Is there a way to check the condition of the function and put it into the list by using list comprehension?

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: yeah I tried it but it got me the value over 10000. I want to get a value that is under 10000 after function evaluated

Comment: what is d(), could you show code of d().

Comment: Your code should work @Chris , could you please add the definition of d

Comment: sorry guys definitely this list comprehension works. it was my problem with the returning the value of function 'd()'

Answer (score 1):

start with a generator

```
a_generator = (d(x) for x in a_list)
# a generator will only evaluate when iterated
my_list = [v for v in a_generator if v < 1000]
# all values should be less than 1000 in this example
max(my_list) # better be less than 1000
```

if the values in `a_list` are sorted from low to high and the rule of

`d(x) < d(x + 1)` is followed you can optimize it further

```
import itertools
a_generator = (d(x) for x in my_sorted_list)
my_list = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda v:v < 1000, a_generator))
# this one will only calculate while the result meets the condition
# once a single value exceeds it will stop taking values
```

you can of coarse easily transform either of these into a single line

```
[v for v in (d(x) for x in a_list) if v < 1000]
```

and

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda v:v < 1000,  (d(x) for x in my_sorted_list)))
```

respectively, but future you and anyone you work with would probably prefer it on 2 lines

Comment: thank you so much! I've learned from another way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can write comprehension as follows:

```
res = [d(x) if d(x) < 10000 else None for x in range(1, 10001)]
number_list = [i for i in res if i is not None]
```

List comprehensions can have two spots where if/else can be used:

```
foo = [{x if <smth> else y if <smth_else> else z} for i in range(1000) {if i % 2 == 0}]
```

The first if-else (inside first pair of curly brackets) determines **what** exactly to put in your list and the second if statement (second pair of curly brackets) determines **when** to do it.

Note: curly brackets are for display purposes only. They shouldn't be used in the actual code.

For example a list comprehension of FizzBuzz would look like this:

```
fb = ['FizzBuzz' if i % 15 == 0 
      else 'Fizz' if i % 3 == 0 
      else 'Buzz' if i % 5 == 0 
      else str(i) 
      for i in range(1, 100)]
```

**EDIT:** Updated as per Joran's comment. I forgot that else statement is necessary when using if-else in the front part of comprehension.

Comment: your first example is wrong ... you would NEED an else clause using the if on that side of the for

Comment: @JoranBeasley Oh yes, you are correct. I'll fix it in a moment.